# How to count the leaves of a Binary Tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BST:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def recurse_add(self, ptr, item):
        if ptr == None:
            return Node(item)
        elif item < ptr.item:
            ptr.left = self.recurse_add(ptr.left, item)
        elif item > ptr.item:
            ptr.right = self.recurse_add(ptr.right, item)
        return ptr
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def count_leaves(self):
        ptr = self.root
        counter = 0
        if ptr.left is None and ptr.right is None:
            counter += 1
        if ptr.left:
            counter += self.count_leaves()
        if ptr.right:
            counter += self.count_leaves()
        return counter
```

I got a `RecursionError`, is there anyway that I could fix this?Can anyone explain to me how I would count the leaves of the binary tree?

Comment: Either raise the recursion limit (`sys.setrecursionlimit`), or don't use recursion.

Comment: How did you get this error? We can't see your tree or where you call the function.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense for your `BST` class to inherit from `Node`. A tree *HAS-A* root node, but you wouldn't ever say a tree *IS-A* node itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 it should return a counter  variable and I test the function with a string, eg >>> 'The number of leaves are', counter

Comment: @Blckknght just took that way

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve] of making a `BST()` instance and calling `add_recurse` on it with some data

Answer (score 2):

You are always repeating from the `self` node when you are counting leaves.

```
def count_leaves(self):
    ptr = self.root  # reseting at the root
    ...
    counter += self.count_leaves()  # recurses from the top of the tree
```

Your secondary problem seems to be related to how you are adding nodes.

For example,

```
def recurse_add(self, ptr, item):
    if prt == None:
        # say this is false
    ptr.left = self.recurse_add(ptr.left, item)
    ...
    return ptr  # The recursive call will return 'ptr.left'
```

So, basically `ptr.left = ptr.left` in the case that `ptr != None`

You need to iterate down. I generally implement all recursive methods onto the Node class rather than pass along a pointer in the Tree class.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.right is None and self.left is None

    def add(self, item):
        if item <= self.item:
            self.left = Node(item) if self.left is None else self.left.add(item)
        elif item > self.item:
            self.right = Node(item) if self.right is None else self.right.add(item)
        return self

    def count_leaves(self):
        counter = 0
        if self.is_leaf():
            counter += 1
        if self.left is not None:
            counter += self.left.count_leaves()
        if self.right is not None:
            counter += self.right.count_leaves()
        return counter
```

Now, just delegate the methods to the root from the tree, if you have a root.

```
class BST:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.root is None

    def add(self, item):
        if self.is_empty():
            self.root = Node(item)
        else:
            self.root.add(item)

    def count_leaves(self):
        return 0 if self.is_empty() else self.root.count_leaves()
```

Comment: Thanks. Good catch

Comment: Then one of your nodes is looping back onto itself. Since we cannot see how you built your tree, it is hard to say